# Building static assets into `./doc` folder of Github pages is not working

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I have been using *Github pages* with a *custom domain* putting all assets including `index.html` in the *root folder* of the repository.

Setting the project to be deployed using Github pages at first; All went well with the default action; `index.html` was served and everything was functional.

Now because I'm trying to modularize and clean the project, nothing is left in the root folder except the necessary build configuration files (along with source).

Locally `npm run build` part of my build process works fine. I can then `serve` files from `docs` folder (because Github uses either root or `docs` folder) my bundle goes to `docs`; So I also changed that configuration in Github pages:

[image]

(The DNS check goes green after seconds.)

So I defined a NodeJS action to replicate my local build process as:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [  main  ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [  main  ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
```

My actions page shows this order:

[image]

I assume that build is done before Github pages does its internal configurations.
I also made sure the `CNAME` file is still there (`/docs`) after each build.

Is using (`/docs`) folder fine to serve the static site ? same as root ?
and is my action being run before Github pages comes into place ?

For reference: my site is inaccessible: https://mylinks.space/

The last thing I can thing of is that because the site is served from a different folder, now `CNAME` file needs time to be propagated (DNS checking).

Comment: But the result of the build isn't actually _in_ the repo, is it? GitHub Pages starts from a clean checkout.

Comment: i see!! I thought the action that follows is (somehow) in the same volume, I didn't pay attention. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe: That was it.

For reference: a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) is to make another branch, add the folder (not ignored) and push that only folder to that branch, for example "gh-pages" branch.

That's a perfect solution for this particular case. I had to remove the folder again from "main" branch though. You can automate the process of git commands with a script.

This is the process for my case: (`docs` in `.gitignore`)

1. Manuel build locally each time
2. Then

```bash
git add docs
git subtree push --prefix docs origin gh-pages
git rm -r docs && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"
git push
```